# Align 3 small images responsively

Tags: image, responsive-design

I have 3 images of 150px by 150px which I would like to center align across all devices. If the screen is large then the 3 images should be evenly spaced across the available width with the 2nd image in the center. If the screen is medium size then the 3rd image is to drop down and be centered in the available width. If the screen is small then the 2nd and 3rd images are to drop down (with the 3rd under the second) and centered in the available width forming a vertical line of 3 images. I have tried the following code but it doesn't work?

```
<div style="text-align: center; width:100%">
<div style="float:left;">
    <img height="150" src="/images/source/ilustracion_guia_03.jpg" width="150" /></div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <img height="150" src="/images/source/ilustracion_guia_07.jpg" width="150" /></div>
<div style="float:right;">
    <img height="150" src="/images/source/ilustracion_guia_04.jpg" width="150" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some edits on your HTML:

```
<div class="allImgsConatainer">
<div class="imgContainer">
    <img height="150" src="/images/source/ilustracion_guia_03.jpg" width="150" /></div>
<div class="imgContainer">
    <img height="150" src="/images/source/ilustracion_guia_07.jpg" width="150" /></div>
<div class="imgContainer">
    <img height="150" src="/images/source/ilustracion_guia_04.jpg" width="150" /></div>
</div>
```

and the style :

```
.allImgsConatainer{
  font-size:0;
  text-align:center;
}
.imgContainer{
    margin:0 0 20px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .imgContainer{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
  }
  .imgContainer:first-of-type{
      text-align:left;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    .imgContainer{
    width:33%;
  }
  .imgContainer:last-of-type{
      text-align:right;
    }
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/fL6u7Ljc/